# Cannot Build APK with 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services

I am starting to use Google Play Services for my little game. Like the guide says, I added `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'` in my `build.gradle(Module: app)`.

Since that change, I cannot build my apk, but I can still run it on my phone. I get following error, while building the apk:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>    Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Thanks

Comment: That could happen by importing the complete library, you should only import needed classes from google play lib. Here in table1 is listed, which parts are available: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `multiDexEnabled` in your `build.gradle` first.

```
defaultConfig {
    // ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

And the other thing I would like to recommend is not to use `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0`. It includes all the services which might not are necessary for your project. So I would like to suggest setting up your `dependencies` more specifically.

For example, I had to add `gcm` and `places` only.

```
dependencies {
    //...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

You'll find specific requirements [from here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

[image: Sample image from the link]

Comment: Thanks, "multiDexEnabled true" seems to help. And now I am using "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'" only.